# ActionView::MissingTemplate for AJAX call and render :json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, passenger

I'm stumped on this one.  I am only having this problem in production, development is working as intended and ajax call succeeds.  In production the call is being made as JSON but I'm getting a missing template error.

**Production Environment:**

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Passenger Nginx
```

**AJAX Call:**

`$.ajax
    url: url
    type: 'PATCH'
    data: purchasing_cost_item: { description: description, total: total}
    dataType: "json"`

**Controller response block:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @purchasing_cost_total, status: 200 }
end
```

**Production Logs:**

```
INFO -- : Started PATCH "/properties/1/purchasing_cost_items/2"

INFO -- : Processing by PurchasingCostItemsController#update as JSON

INFO -- :   Parameters: {"purchasing_cost_item"=>{"description"=>"Test description", "total"=>"1690"}, "property_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}

INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

FATAL -- : ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template purchasing_cost_items/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json, :js, :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif,
 :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
```

Comment: you can simply use `render json: {purchasing_cost_total: @purchasing_cost_total, status: 200}`

Comment: That is often the error I get when rails is using the `ujs` system and is trying to call `update.js.erb`. I am not sure if that would be helpful for debugging.